# OpenShift oc apply and rollout

Tags: openshift

I would like to perform the following script in our test-environment to deploy our application in OpenShift 4.8.

```
oc apply -f deployment-config.yaml
oc rollout latest dc/my-application
```

The trigger in deployment config is ConfigChange. If e.g. an environment variable has changed in deployment config `oc apply -f deployment-config.yaml` will trigger a rollout.

The deployment config uses snapshot as image. We don't have a version number of our snapshot which means that a new snapshot might need to be deployed even though deployment config has not been changed. Thats why we use `oc rollout latest dc/my-application`.

```
image: "<repo-url>/my-application:snapshot"
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

The problem is that sometimes both `oc apply -f deployment-config.yaml` and `oc rollout latest dc/my-application` will trigger a rollout.

Is there a way to do `oc apply -f deployment-config.yaml` without triggering a rollout? Or do you se another solution?

Comment: You can remove `configChange` trigger, otherwise, the most probably obviously not https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/deployments/basic_deployment_operations.html#config-change-trigger

Comment: And by "remove" you mean setting it to empty?
What do you mean by "otherwise, the most probably obviously not"?

Comment: if you will be triggering deployment manually, then you dont need config change trigger, if there are no any other triggers, you can just delete the whole triggers section in the deployment config

Answer (score 1):

As of [Deployment triggers](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/applications/deployments/managing-deployment-processes.html#deployments-triggers_deployment-operations) you need to define the trigger as empty field. If you just remove the trigger, a config change trigger will be added by default.

> If no triggers are defined on a DeploymentConfig object, a config change trigger is added by default. If triggers are defined as an empty field, deployments must be started manually.